# Jaakko Hintikka: "everybody has a unique hobby"

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, second-order-logic

At the bottom of page 58 of Jaakko Hintikka's *Principles of Mathematics Revisited* he gives a formula in his IF first-order logic

$(\forall x)(\forall z)(\exists y / \forall z)(\exists u / \forall x)(((x=z)\leftrightarrow (y=u)) \& \mathrm{H}(x,y) \& \mathrm{H}(z,u) \& \sim \mathrm{H}(x,u) \& \sim\mathrm{H}(z,y))$

which he says is equivalent to the second-order formula (top of page 59)

$(\exists f)(\forall x)(\forall z)(((x\neq z) \supset (f(x)\neq f(z))) \& \mathrm{H}(x,f(x)) \& \mathrm{H}(z,f(z)) \& \sim \mathrm{H}(x,f(z))\&\sim \mathrm{H}(z,f(x)))$

He says if $\mathrm{H}(x,y)$ is read "$y$ is a hobby of $x$'s" then these say something like "everybody has a unique hobby''. (He also says that these cannot be reduced to any expression in ordinary first-order logic.)

Is there a mistake in those formulas? When $x=z$ then they both require $\mathrm{H}(x,y)$ and $\sim \mathrm{H}(x,y)$. If there is a mistake, what could he have meant? If there isn't a mistake, what's my mistake?

Comment: When $x=z$ both formulas are False, and this is consistent with the asserted "equivalence".

Comment: the formula "says that one can correlate with each $x$ an individual $f(x)$ such that the correlates of two different individuals are different and differ from each other in the way indicated". If we consider two identical individual $x=z$, we may expect that the formula turns out False.

Comment: For me it seems that the second formula correctly would be with the parentheses rearranged: $(x\ne z) \supset \big(\, (f(x)\ne f(z)) & H(x, f(x)) & \dots\,\big)$.